# Log response times for all HTTP requests from a docker container

Tags: python, docker, httprequest, http-proxy

I have built a docker image that contains a pre-built application that I cannot add logging statements to. The application makes many HTTP requests as it executes, and I would like to log those requests, and in particular, the time it takes for those responses to be fulfilled. Is there something I add to my docker container, such as a proxy, that would allow me to log response times to all outgoing HTTP requests?

Comment: There is nothing native in Docker that would do this.  Docker doesn't generally look at the contents of network streams at all so it wouldn't know if a given TCP connection has a single HTTP request, more than one, a database request, or something else.

Comment: I have seen mentions of using a sidecar container to do this, using tools such as Prometheus, Datadog, and Envoy. I've never used (or even heard of) sidecars, so I'm looking into that method, but it would be nice if there was something I could add to my docker so that I only have to deploy and manage one container.

Comment: Thinking about it a bit more, a sidecar wouldn't work for this setup, since I will be running the docker container in AWS Batch, and that doesn't allow me to deploy a sidecar.

Comment: Stick Nginx or Traefik in front of the app and get the logging data from that.

Comment: @HansKilian Could you explain a little more of what you mean? If you put your answer in an answer to this question, then I can accept it as the answer if it works.

Answer (score 0):

## Log outgoing requests

To log outgoing requests, you can set up Nginx as a *forward proxy*.

To illustrate, I've created this Flask app which makes a request to Google when we hit the `/` endpoint.

```
from flask import Flask
import requests

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    r = requests.get('http://www.google.com')
    return r.text
```

and Dockerfile

```
FROM python:latest
WORKDIR /app
RUN pip install flask requests
COPY hello.py .
CMD flask --app hello run --host=0.0.0.0
```

We then configure Nginx to listen on port 80 and pass all requests on to the host indicated in the request

```
log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                             '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                             '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                             '"$upstream_response_time"';

server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    resolver 8.8.8.8;
    proxy_pass http://$http_host$uri$is_args$args;
  }
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_time;
}
```

I've added a custom log format that logs the response time from the server we're calling.

We can then orchestrate the 2 containers using Docker Compose like this. Note that we're setting the `http_proxy` environment variable for the application container. That causes it to pass all outgoing requests to the proxy container instead of calling directly.

```
version: '3'

services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
    environment:
      - http_proxy=http://nginx/
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

Now we can run the containers, make a request and check the log with

```
docker compose up -d
curl http://localhost:5000/
docker compose logs nginx
```

At the end of the log messages, you'll see the response time from the server (in the example, it's Google). My log looks like this and shows a response time of 112ms.

```
172.24.0.3 - - [10/Oct/2023:20:14:46 +0000] "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1" 200 8264 "-" "python-requests/2.31.0" "0.112"
```

## Log incoming requests

If you want to log incoming requests, you can set up Nginx as a *reverse proxy*.

To create an app to measure, I've used this Dockerfile that creates a template C# web API application that listens on port 80 and responds to requests on `/weatherforecast`. I've used this since I'm familiar with it and it's easy to set up. You should use your application instead.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
RUN dotnet new webapi -n myapp -o . --no-https
RUN dotnet publish -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app /app
CMD ["dotnet", "myapp.dll"]
```

We'll orchestrate the application and Nginx using this docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3'

services:
  myapp:
    build: .
  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    ports:
      - 8000:80
    volumes:
      - ./nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

This runs the application ('myapp') and Nginx. Nginx listens on the host's port 8000 and is configured with a file called nginx.conf which looks like this:

```
log_format upstream_time '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                             '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                             '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
                             '"$upstream_response_time"';
server {
  listen 80;
  location / {
    proxy_pass http://myapp/;
  }
  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log upstream_time;
}
```

In this file we've specified a custom log format for Nginx that includes `$upstream_response_time` as the last part of the log entries. Nginx is also configured to pass all requests on to the `myapp` application.

Run it, make a couple of requests and look at the Nginx log using

```
docker compose up -d
curl http://localhost:8000/weatherforecast
curl http://localhost:8000/weatherforecast
docker compose logs nginx
```

My output looks like this, with the response times logged as 68 ms and 3 ms for the two requests (the response times are at the end of the log entries)

```
nginx_1  | 172.22.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2023:09:51:16 +0000] "GET /weatherforecast HTTP/1.1" 200 394 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "0.068"
nginx_1  | 172.22.0.1 - - [07/Oct/2023:09:52:13 +0000] "GET /weatherforecast HTTP/1.1" 200 393 "-" "curl/7.81.0" "0.003"
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. It looks like you've setup a reverse proxy that will log all incoming requests and response times. I need to be able to log all outgoing requests that originate in the application that my docker container wraps. Do you know of a way to setup a proxy to do that?

Comment: @Gillfish Ah, I missed that you wanted to log outgoing requests. I've added a section on outgoing requests to my answer.